# How to block app using local proxy server in ios or redirect the network call to a nonexistant_invalid_url which match to proxy settings match domain

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, networkextension

I am trying to block app using proxy server.VPN is also working well,when i add this line

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
                            config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                            config.urlCache = nil
                            let session = URLSession.init(configuration: config)
                            let url = URL(string: "https://nonexistant_invalid_url")
                            let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                            return
```

But got error is

2022-03-14 12:42:46.257048+0530 pushNotifications[1370:272455] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
Starting
2022-03-14 12:42:55.375340+0530 pushNotifications[1370:272736] Connection 1: received failure notification
2022-03-14 12:42:55.375513+0530 pushNotifications[1370:272736] Connection 1: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2022-03-14 12:42:55.375574+0530 pushNotifications[1370:272736] Connection 1: encountered error(12:8)
2022-03-14 12:42:55.377315+0530 pushNotifications[1370:272736] Task .<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2022-03-14 12:42:55.385009+0530 pushNotifications[1370:272737] Task .<1> finished with error [-1003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x2827f6520 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns, kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>, NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask .<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://nonexistant_invalid_url/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://nonexistant_invalid_url/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}

View controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var providerManager: NETunnelProviderManager!
    @IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
     }
    
    
    @IBAction func vpnConnectionSwitch(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if(mySwitch.isOn){
            self.loadProviderManager {
                //self.configureVPN(serverAddress: "hix",username: "JornVPN", password: "6ztbe85")
                self.configureVPN(serverAddress: "serveradress",username: "J", password: "6ztbe85")
            }
                }
                else {
                   print( "Switch is Off")
// Of on demand
                    let rule = NEOnDemandRuleDisconnect()
                    rule.interfaceTypeMatch = .any
                    self.providerManager?.onDemandRules = [ rule ]
                    
                    
                    
                    self.providerManager?.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                          if error == nil  {
                             self.providerManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                                 self.providerManager?.connection.stopVPNTunnel()
                                 print("Stop")
                             })
                          }
                    })
                    

                }
    }
    

    func loadProviderManager(completion:@escaping () -> Void) {
       NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences { (managers, error) in
           if error == nil {
               self.providerManager = managers?.first ?? NETunnelProviderManager()
               completion()
           }
       }
    }

    func configureVPN( serverAddress: String,username: String, password: String) {

        guard
            let configurationFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ios", withExtension: ".ovpn"),
                let configData = try? Data(contentsOf: configurationFileURL)
            else {
                fatalError()
            }
        
        


      self.providerManager?.loadFromPreferences { error in
         if error == nil {
            let tunnelProtocol = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
             
            tunnelProtocol.username = username
            tunnelProtocol.serverAddress = serverAddress
            tunnelProtocol.providerBundleIdentifier = "com.cloud.pushNotifications.tunnel" // bundle id of the network extension target
            tunnelProtocol.providerConfiguration = ["ovpn": configData, "username": username, "password": password]
            tunnelProtocol.disconnectOnSleep = false
            self.providerManager.protocolConfiguration = tunnelProtocol
            self.providerManager.localizedDescription = "JornVPN" // the title of the VPN profile which will appear on Settings
            self.providerManager.isEnabled = true
             self.providerManager.isOnDemandEnabled = true
    // VPN ON DEMAND
             let rule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
             rule.interfaceTypeMatch = .any
             self.providerManager.onDemandRules = [ rule ]
             
          

            self.providerManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                  if error == nil  {
                     self.providerManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                         do {
                           try self.providerManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                             
                             print("Starting")// starts the VPN tunnel.
                             let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
                            config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                            config.urlCache = nil
                            let session = URLSession.init(configuration: config)
                            let url = URL(string: "https://nonexistant_invalid_url")
                            let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                            return
                                
                            }
                            task.resume()
                         } catch let error {
                             print(error.localizedDescription)
                         }
                     })
                  }
            })
          }
       }
    }

}
```

Packet Tunnel:

```
import NetworkExtension
import OpenVPNAdapter
import UIKit
import NEKit

class PacketTunnelProvider: NEPacketTunnelProvider {
    
    
    let proxyServerPort: UInt16 = 9090;
    let proxyServerAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    var proxyServer: GCDHTTPProxyServer!
    
    
    var startHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)?
    var stopHandler: (() -> Void)?
    var vpnReachability = OpenVPNReachability()

    var configuration: OpenVPNConfiguration!
    var properties: OpenVPNConfigurationEvaluation!
    var UDPSession: NWUDPSession!
    var TCPConnection: NWTCPConnection!

    lazy var vpnAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter = {
        let adapter = OpenVPNAdapter()
        adapter.delegate = self
        return adapter
    }()
    
    override func startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        print("Conneted \(options)")
        NSLog("Conneted \(options)")
        guard
            let protocolConfiguration = protocolConfiguration as? NETunnelProviderProtocol,
            let providerConfiguration = protocolConfiguration.providerConfiguration
            else {
                fatalError()
        }
        guard let ovpnFileContent: Data = providerConfiguration["ovpn"] as? Data else { return }
            let configuration = OpenVPNConfiguration()
            configuration.fileContent = ovpnFileContent
            do {
                properties = try vpnAdapter.apply(configuration: configuration)
            } catch {
                completionHandler(error)
                return
            }
        configuration.tunPersist = true

        if !properties.autologin {
            if let username: String = providerConfiguration["username"] as? String, let password: String = providerConfiguration["password"] as? String {
                let credentials = OpenVPNCredentials()
                credentials.username = username
                credentials.password = password
                do {
                    try vpnAdapter.provide(credentials: credentials)
                    print("vpnAdapter")
                } catch {
                    completionHandler(error)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        vpnReachability.startTracking { [weak self] status in
            guard status != .notReachable else { return }
            self?.vpnAdapter.reconnect(afterTimeInterval: 5)
        }
        startHandler = completionHandler
        vpnAdapter.connect(using: packetFlow)
    

    }

    override func stopTunnel(with reason: NEProviderStopReason, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        stopHandler = completionHandler
        if vpnReachability.isTracking {
            vpnReachability.stopTracking()
        }
        vpnAdapter.disconnect()
    }

    override func handleAppMessage(_ messageData: Data, completionHandler: ((Data?) -> Void)?) {
        if let handler = completionHandler {
            handler(messageData)
        }
    }

    override func sleep(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }

    override func wake() {
    }

}

extension PacketTunnelProvider: OpenVPNAdapterDelegate {
    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, configureTunnelWithNetworkSettings networkSettings: NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        networkSettings?.dnsSettings?.matchDomains = [""]

                // Set the network settings for the current tunneling session.
                setTunnelNetworkSettings(networkSettings, completionHandler: completionHandler)
        //proxy Server
        let settings = NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings(tunnelRemoteAddress: proxyServerAddress)
        settings.mtu = NSNumber(value: 1500)

        let proxySettings = NEProxySettings()
        proxySettings.httpEnabled = true;
        proxySettings.httpServer = NEProxyServer(address: proxyServerAddress, port: Int(proxyServerPort))
        proxySettings.httpsEnabled = true;
        proxySettings.httpsServer = NEProxyServer(address: proxyServerAddress, port: Int(proxyServerPort))
        proxySettings.excludeSimpleHostnames = false;
        proxySettings.exceptionList = []
        proxySettings.matchDomains = ["https://www.facebook.com/","https://m.facebook.com/","https://www.google.com/","https://google.com/"]
        settings.dnsSettings = NEDNSSettings(servers: ["127.0.0.1"])
        settings.proxySettings = proxySettings;
        RawSocketFactory.TunnelProvider = self
    
        self.setTunnelNetworkSettings(settings, completionHandler: { error in
            guard error == nil else {
                completionHandler(error)
                return
            }
            let newProxyServer = GCDHTTPProxyServer(address: IPAddress(fromString: self.proxyServerAddress), port: Port(port: self.proxyServerPort))
            self.proxyServer = newProxyServer
            do {
                try self.proxyServer.start()
                completionHandler(nil)
            } catch let proxyError {
                completionHandler(proxyError)
            }
        })
    }
    

    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, configureTunnelWithNetworkSettings networkSettings: NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings?, completionHandler: @escaping (OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow?) -> Void) {
        setTunnelNetworkSettings(networkSettings) { (error) in
            completionHandler(error == nil ? self.packetFlow : nil)
        }
    }

    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, handleEvent event: OpenVPNAdapterEvent, message: String?) {
        switch event {
        case .connected:
            if reasserting {
                reasserting = false
            }
            guard let startHandler = startHandler else { return }
            startHandler(nil)
            self.startHandler = nil
        case .disconnected:
            guard let stopHandler = stopHandler else { return }
            if vpnReachability.isTracking {
                vpnReachability.stopTracking()
            }
            stopHandler()
            self.stopHandler = nil
        case .reconnecting:
            reasserting = true
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, handleError error: Error) {
        guard let fatal = (error as NSError).userInfo[OpenVPNAdapterErrorFatalKey] as? Bool, fatal == true else {
            return
        }
        NSLog("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        NSLog("Connection Info: \(vpnAdapter.connectionInformation.debugDescription)")
        if vpnReachability.isTracking {
            vpnReachability.stopTracking()
        }

        if let startHandler = startHandler {
            startHandler(error)
            self.startHandler = nil
        } else {
            cancelTunnelWithError(error)
        }
    }

    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, handleLogMessage logMessage: String) {
        NSLog("Log: \(logMessage)")
    }

}


extension PacketTunnelProvider: OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow {
    func readPackets(completionHandler: @escaping ([Data], [NSNumber]) -> Void) {
        packetFlow.readPackets(completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    func writePackets(_ packets: [Data], withProtocols protocols: [NSNumber]) -> Bool {
        return packetFlow.writePackets(packets, withProtocols: protocols)
    }

}
extension NEPacketTunnelFlow: OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow {
    
}
```

Comment: What is the point of blocking the app. Using proxy/VPN is not only to prevent add or bypass geographic restrictions. This is also used for security reason in companies .

Comment: we want to create a application which will reduce the screen time of user just like lockdown iOS in order to do that we are trying to create a local proxy server and then redirecting specific URL to non existing URL

Comment: This is expected because you are connecting to "nonexistant_invalid_url", they just add this dummy connection to activate the tunnel.